# Are edits that just format code valid?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, code-formatting

While on the [Suggested Edits review stream](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), I encounter an edit that just formats the code, and nothing else. For an example, see [edit #1492671](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1429671).

I normally just accept these as they make the code easier to read, but sometimes there are other issues in the post that should have been fixed also. So, where do we draw the line?

Comment: I personally would have gone in to improve it and would have unaccepted the "helpful" box. If you can't even be bothered to fix the "y"/"why" as a bare minimum...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code formatting is a valid edit if it is not very minor. In the example edit you provided the edit is very little and did not bring much readability to the post.

But sometimes it turns an unreadable question in a very readable with a few spaces added.

If the editor forgot to change other issues then just hit *improve* and fix it.